# Django Class Based Views handle multiple queries

Tags: django

I'm rewriting my django function view to class based views. I have this current function

```
@login_required
def settings(request, template_name="settings.html"):
    context = {}

    context['kcs'] = KlarnaProfile.objects.filter(user_profile__user=request.user)
    context['extends'] = ExtendProfile.objects.filter(user_profile__user=request.user)
    context['fortnoxs'] = FortnoxProfile.objects.filter(user_profile__user=request.user)
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

that confirms first if a user is logged in and then get's information linked to that user account

here's what I've got as my class based view

```
class SettingsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "settings.html"

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

how can I add the three filters that use the logged in user as a filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [get_context_data](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/#get_context_data) method like this:

```
class SettingsView(TemplateView):
    ...

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context_data['kcs'] = KlarnaProfile.objects.filter(user_profile__user=self.request.user)
        ...

        return context_data
```

---

**Neat pick.** Instead of doing:

```
class SettingsView(TemplateView):
    ...

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can do:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class SettingsView(TemplateView):
    ...
```

You might want to read [Decorating the class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) from Django's official documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question?